# Find "Request time out" when tracert command is running via batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have to check multiple ip addresses. So, I make a batch file to get all ip result as shown in below.

```
@echo off
if exist D:\tracert\computers.txt goto Label1
echo.
echo Cannot find d:\tracert\computers.txt
echo.
Pause
goto :eof

:Label1
for /f %%i in (d:\tracert\computers.txt) do call :trace %%i
notepad D:\tracert\%1.txt
goto :eof

:trace
echo Tracing %1
tracert -h 200 %1 >> D:\tracert\testing.csv
```

In `computers.txt` file, I write all ip line by line.

The above code has no problem and I can get the result correctly. But, the problem is, I can't try to find `Request time out.` when I run `tracert` command.

I want to find `Request time out.` and if found, I want to stop current tracert command and write result into a file and loop for next ip again. If not found, just only write result into a file.

The main reason that I want to make like this because I want to reduce the amount of time taken when I run this batch file.

So, I change the code like this but it doesn't work.

```
:trace
echo Tracing %1
tracert -h 200 %1 
if find /c /i "Request time out." GEQ 0 (
    echo %1>>D:\tracert\%1.txt
    goto :Label1
) else ( echo %1>>D:\tracert\%1.txt )
notepad D:\tracert\%1.txt
```

I'm not sure I can search as shown in above because I'm in newbie in batch.
I'm very appreciate for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea, *only for the fix and subject to the `find` string being correct*:

```bat
:trace
echo Tracing %1
tracert -h 200 %1 | find /i "Request time out" && (
    >>D:\tracert\%1.txt echo %1) || (>>D:\tracert\%1.txt echo %1
    goto :Label1)
start D:\tracert\%1.txt
```

*You really should learn to use double quotes to protect string/variable content, but that is outside of the scope of your question so has been left untouched.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But, I can't get the tracert result in the `.txt` files. It only show ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have the spelling correct, else you will not find the string. Notice the `d` in `timed`

```
@echo off
:trace
echo Tracing %1
tracert -h 200 %1 | find /i "Request timed out" >>%1.txt
```

Secondly, the IP will always return a valid IP or something starting with Request. So this will also work.

```
@echo off
:trace
echo Tracing %1
tracert -h 200 %1 | find /i "Request" >>%1.txt
```

It will therefore echo to `hostname01.txt` the content will be:

> 2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
>
> 3     *        *        *     Request timed out.